# C++ getline not working with double

Tags: c++, double, getline

For some reason getline will not work with a double and it gives me a message saying "getline no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list argument types are: (std::istream, double)" if I change the doubles to strings it works so I am unsure what the problem is, if anyone could help it would be much appreciated

Comment: You should check the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/
getline doesn't take a double argument, as it's telling you.  it's there to get lines of data (aka char arrays / strings) not numbers.  You want to use atoi or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is for reading *strings*. And only strings. If you want to get a floating point value read it as a string and [convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) to a floating point value. Or use the input operator `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cin >> athOneTime;
```

to extract a `double`. If you want to skip the rest of the line, use

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurs because `getline()` reads only strings. To read a double, you must use `cin`.

Comment: What value does your answer add over the other answers?

Comment: Eu dei uma resposta mais simples para entender